# Different dates when used new Date("2014 Aug 11") and new Date("2014-08-11") in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, date-parsing

`new Date("2014 Aug 11")` gives `Mon Aug 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` which's correct, but

`new Date("2014-08-11")` gives `Mon Aug 11 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`.

Why there's 1 hour difference in these 2 dates?

I am trying to subtract 2 dates and expect result to be '0' if both the dates are same. But in my example above it's not ZERO!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's perfeclty explained in [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) on the `parse` function (whose parsing [is used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) in the `Date` constructor) :

> Given a date string of "March 7, 2014", parse assumes a local time zone, but given an ISO format such as  "2014-03-07" it will assume a time zone of UTC. Therefore Date objects produced using those strings will represent different moments in time unless the system is set with a local time zone of UTC

Somebody who's in GMT+2 would see a difference of 2 hours.

If you can't properly parse the dates and you're confident about the type of strings you get as input, you might force the timezone :

```
var date = new Date(str+" UTC");
```

Answer (score 0):

For your query youcan try this new Date() format

new Date("2014,08,11") It gives Mon Aug 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time).